# How can I efficiently access members from inner classes using instances of a class which includes inner classes?

Tags: c++, oop, inner-classes

I want to design a structure using 5 particular classes:Person,Driver,Employee,Child and Parent.

-Every driver is a person.

-Every employee is both a driver and a person.

-Every child is a person.

-Every parent is a person,driver,employee and it can have one or more children.

Here's what I had in mind:

```
class Parent {
public:
    class Employee {
    public:
        class Driver {
        public:
            class Person {
                string name;
                int age;
            public:
                string GetName() { return name; }
                void SetName(string name) { this->name = name; }
                int GetAge() { return age; }
                void SetAge(int age) { this->age = age; }
            };
        private:
            Person person;
            string carName;
        public:
            Person GetPerson() { return person;}
            void SetPerson(Person person) { this->person = person;}
            string GetCarName() { return carName; }
            void SetCarName(string carName) { this->carName = carName;}
        };
    private:
        Driver driver;
    public:
        Driver GetDriver() { return driver; }
        void SetDriver(Driver driver) { this->driver = driver; }
    };
    class Child {
    public:
        class Person:public Employee::Driver::Person {
        };
    private:
        Person person;
        string nameOfSchool;
    public:
        Person GetPerson() { return person; }
        void SetPerson(Person person) { this->person = person;}
        string GetNameOfSchool(){ return nameOfSchool;}
        void SetNameOfSchool(string nameOfSchool) { this->nameOfSchool = nameOfSchool;}
    };
private:
    Employee employee;
    Child child;
public:
    Employee GetEmployee() { return employee; }
    void SetEmployee(Employee employee) { this->employee = employee;}
    Child GetChild() { return child;}
    void SetChild(Child child) { this->child = child;}
};
```

But when I try something like:

```
Parent random_parent;
    random_parent.GetEmployee().GetDriver().GetPerson().SetName("Joseph");
    random_parent.GetEmployee().GetDriver().GetPerson().SetAge(80);
    cout << random_parent.GetEmployee().GetDriver().GetPerson().GetName() << endl << random_parent.GetEmployee().GetDriver().GetPerson().GetAge();
```

I get just this garbage value:

```
-858993460
```

How can I make any instance of `Parent` work and be able to access and initialize the `name` and `age` from inner class `Person`?

Comment: Your `GetEmployee` and `GetDriver` and `GetPerson` functions need to return references to the *original* object you are trying to update, instead of returning copies of it which get thrown away at the end of the statement.

Comment: I think you want to use inheritance rather than making everything an inner class

Comment: @AlanBirtles problem is,that i'm supposed to make them either designing nested classes,forward classes or friend classes.Otherwise,I would have also relied on inheritance mainly.

Comment: @user253751 So basically those getters should be pointer functions?

Comment: What AlanBirtles said is also true. Right now, every parent has an employee and a child. Every employee has a driver. Every driver has a person. Every child also has a person. This doesn't make logical sense. I thought maybe writing the code this way is helpful for other reasons, but that doesn't seem to be the case either. (Code doesn't *have* to be OOP)

Comment: @user253751 What do you mean by "writing the code this way is helpful for other reasons"?Since you don't know yet what I'm using for.For the record,right now I am trying to test and see how this whole class composition works and how I  can implement it in the most efficient way.Also,can you elaborate why this doesn't make sense?

Comment: @Neri-kun Well there are other reasons to write code a particular way than "it's like the real world". For example, a video game might get a speed boost  (for complicated reasons) by storing the position of each game object *separately* from the object itself. In which case I might wonder why the position wasn't part of the object, and then I might find out they did it for speed. There are often reasons to write illogical-seeming code. Your code seems illogical, and I don't see a reason why it should be that way.

Comment: @user253751 I get your point regarding the video game stuff.As to why I conceived that code that way is because I have somehow come to the conclusion that the focus should be on instances of ```Parent```,therefore I thought that classes revolving around class ```Parent``` should be somehow masked.

Comment: Inheritance can be a simple approach for this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GetPerson`, `GetDriver`, `GetChild` and `GetEmployee` should return either references or pointers. Right now, when you call `random_parent.GetEmployee()`, it returns a brand new, temporary, `Employee` object which is a copy of the one in `random_parent`. If you do `random_parent.GetEmployee().SetDriver(new_driver)`, it sets the driver in this brand new `Employee` object, not the one in `random_parent`. The temporary `Employee` object is then discarded after the statement is executed.

If you change

```
Employee GetEmployee() { return employee; }
```

to

```
//     here
//      |
//      V
Employee& GetEmployee() { return employee; }
```

then `random_parent.GetEmployee()` will return a *reference* to the `employee` object in `random_parent`. `random_parent.GetEmployee().SetDriver(new_driver);` will update that object, which is what you expected to happen.

Do the same with `GetDriver`, `GetPerson`, and `GetChild`.

---

This fixes your immediate problem. However, your code is poorly designed. You could get design advice on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I am aware that my design is poorly conceived.Like I said before,I don't how to make improvements such that I end up using forward, friend or nested classes in my design.P.S:Thanks for fixing this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Design-wise, driver, employee, child and parent are not descendants of a Person. They are rather *roles* and one Person can have any number of roles. Or, they can be *relationships* between 2 persons, where, for example, a person is child to one person and a parent to another.